# Shell Script: Copy Multiple Files and add Timestamp

Tags: bash, shell

I have a folder that contains a few `.db` files and I am trying to create a shell script that copies every `*.db` file but adds the current date to the file

For example, the folder contains `A.db`, `B.db`, `C.db`. I want it to copy `A.db` to `/Backups/A_2016_07_21.db` and so on.

I know I can do `cp -a A.db /Backups/A.db` but I am looking for a more automated way to do it for every `*.db` file and also add the current date

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iterate over the files using a `for` construct and `cp` files to the destination with getting desired file names using `bash` parameter expansion and `date`:

```
for f in *.db; do cp -a "$f" /Backups/""${f%.db}"_$(date '+%Y_%m_%d').db"; done
```

Comment: Tip: do a cd /working/directory first as putting an absolute path in the for doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

You can use a one line for loop.

```
for file in $( ls /dir/*.db ); do cp $file /Backups/$( echo $file | cut -d. -f1 )_$( date +%Y_%m_%d ).$( echo $file | cut -d. -f2 ); done
```

Break down:
for file in $( ls /dir/*.db ) - makes a list of all .db files

cp $file - copies the files (pretty self-explanatory)

/Backups/$( echo $file | cut -d. -f1 ) - extracts the first part of the filename. e.g. A.db -> A

*$( date +%Y*%m_%d ) - prints the date, with an underscore in front.

.$( echo $file | cut -d. -f2 ) - and finally extracts the last part of the filename with a prefix of "."

Comment: This is not a good idea! It will fail if any file has a space in its name, if any file has a newline in its name, if any file has more than one dot in its name and it also creates 2+ unnecessary processes per file....